# How to prevent a subprocess from outputting to stdout in Python?

Tags: python, shell, anaconda, subprocess, stdout

I need to run a process using Python and kill it and then rerun it when it hangs. And I don't want the second process to contaminate my shell stdout. But no matter what I do, the subprocess's output is written to the shell. BTW, I'm using Linux.

This is what I have:

```py
server_command = "./start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1"
server_cwd = "/home/mehran/Project"

process = subprocess.Popen(server_command,
                           shell=False,
                           cwd=server_cwd,
                           stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                           stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

As I mentioned, this will still print the output of the subprocess to shell. I have also tried all the other combinations I could think of (without `>/dev/null 2>&1` and then without `subprocess.DEVNULL`)

**[UPDATE]**

To answer some of the comments, I've tested the following cases with the same results:

- `shell=True`
- `[server_command]`
- `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`

I added the last one even though the `start.sh` script does not read anything from the stdin. TBH, I didn't completely read the script but as far as I can tell, it does a `conda activate .` and runs another python program. The thing is that I would rather not touch that script and suppress the output no matter the situation within that script.

**[UPDATE]**

I forgot to mention this, when I run the script manually in a terminal like this:

```
./start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I get **no output** which makes me wonder why the same approach does not work when called from Python code!

**[UPDATE]**

If anyone's interested to replicate this issue, please clone the following project:

https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui

And then run:

```
./start_linux.sh --api
```

This is the script that I'm trying to control within my code. It's just that you also need to send an HTTP request to load a model to see the output I mentioned:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:5000/api/v1/model \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"action": "load", "model_name": "TheBloke_WizardLM-1.0-Uncensored-CodeLlama-34B-AWQ"}'
```

The `model_name` refers to a model that you have downloaded into the app. It's pretty simple in fact.

Comment: You said `shell=False`, so no one is going to handle the `>/dev/null` and `2>&1` parameters.  The DEVNULL parameters should be enough to suppress the output.  What does the process do?  Is it possibly doing its own terminal stuff?

Comment: try also `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`. If your script writes to `/dev/tty`, I think you'll have to `setsid()`.

Comment: If I replace your command with "ls", no output is produced.  We need to know more about what's in `start.sh`.  Are you, perhaps, doing a `sudo` or `ssh` that needs a password?

Comment: You should pass `server_command` as a `list`, not a `str`, when `shell=False`. Passing a `str` has different, platform-dependent behavior.

Comment: Could be writing to `/dev/tty`. For example, the way that the shell utility [vipe](https://github.com/madx/moreutils/blob/master/vipe) works is that it open `/dev/tty` so that it can pop open a text editor, then it writes its normal output to stdout. You could use `strace` to figure out exactly how it's writing to stdout.

Comment: If `stdout=DEVNULL` and you're still seeing content at the terminal, _it's not writing to stdout_ and the question is based on a false premise. Maybe it's writing to the TTY -- but you need to figure that out to know how to proceed. If you use `strace` or such to figure out _how the writes are being done_, you'll be able to build a [mre] and ask a better question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Let's say that the script is writing to TTY. What is the solution fo that?

Comment: @Mehran, ...typically, to try to make sure there's no controlling TTY available for it to grab; _or_ you could use a tool like `unbuffer` to make a fake TTY that really writes to stdout and thus can be redirected by redirecting stdout.

Comment: BTW, you can't use redirections with `shell=False`, and don't need to (`stdin=`, `stdout=` and `stderr=` do the same work in `subprocess` that `<`, `>` and `2>` would in shell). `server_command` should be `["./start.sh"]` -- the `>/dev/null 2>&1` is shell source code, if you actually tried to use that with `shell=False` on a UNIXy system you'd get a file-not-found exception with no child process launched at all, because Python would be telling your OS to run a script with `>/dev/null 2>&1` as part of its filename. Or with unbuffer, the correct thing is `["unbuffer", "./start.sh"]`

Comment: ...the fact that you say you're getting messages written by the child when you use the original code shown in the question -- when that code has bugs that mean it could never start a child process at all -- makes me wonder if you're confusing error messages written _by the parent Python process_ because it can't start the child with error messages written _by the child itself_.

Comment: If you can provide a [mre] others can run without changes to see the same problem, that would cut down greatly on the room for speculation. Maybe test using an online sandbox like https://repl.it/ to make sure you've generated something that behaves the same way as your real code when run in isolation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can assure you that the text is not an error message (neither from the parent project, nor from the child process). It's a progress bar. I'm going to update the question so you can replicate the issue if you like. Thank you.

Comment: (There are other, weirder cases within the realm of imagination, like programs that directly use `/proc/$PPID/fd/1` to undo any redirections during their invocation; but let's rule out horses before we go zebra-hunting).

Comment: Okay, first note, progress bars aren't written to stdout conventionally, so redirecting stdout is redirecting the wrong thing. Progress bars are diagnostic content for human operators to gague program progress, so the correct file descriptor for them is stderr (reserved by POSIX for "diagnostic output"; logs and error messages are diagnostic, but so are progress bars and prompts). Keeping progress data on stderr is also practical: If you run `curl >outfile`, you don't want the progress bar in `outfile`.

Comment: but yes, I'm looking forward to that update.

Comment: (Mind, in `curl >outfile 2>diags` you might not want progress bar data mixed in with `diags` either, hence it being not unheard of to write progress bars direct to the TTY, or -- more often -- just turn them off by default if `isatty(2)` is false)

Comment: ...okay, so for your curl call, if you don't want a progress bar, that's what `curl --no-progress-meter` is for. Much saner to just amend your curl options to turn off the individual feature you don't want _without_ throwing away all your access to diagnostics if something goes wrong.

Comment: (that said, _no_, "go clone this 3rd-party code" is not a reasonable [mre]; I'm not going to audit someone else's repo to decide if I trust it when the only payoff is getting to answer a Stack Overflow question; part of the point of the [mre] definition is making something **minimal** -- code short enough to put in the question is short enough to audit by eyeball; it also has the effect of making the question self-contained so it and its answers are still useful to others even after the repo no longer exists or has been updated to no longer trigger the bug).

Comment: There's been a misunderstanding. First thing is that curl is only run to force the app to show the progress bar. The progress bar does not belong to curl. Secondly, I didn't write the `start.sh` script. That's why I mentioned the git repo. I'm just trying to suppress the output of that script. I have no idea why it's so hard to suppress it.

Comment: It sounds to me then like it's a process started by `./start_linux.sh --api` that's writing the output, and `./start.sh` is just the trigger by way of making the request. If you kill any such processes that previously exist, and then make it, say, `./start_linux.sh --api </dev/null >start_linux.log 2>&1`, does that solve the problem?

Comment: ..._if so_, that implies that this question was based on a false premise (that the output was coming from `start.sh`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My apologies. I didn't mean to deceive you. It's just that I didn't know that fact matters. The bash script runs a Python script.

Comment: Every process inherits its parent's file descriptors, and keeps them during its execution until/unless it does something to change that copy of the table; so when you run `start.sh`, the Python script it starts in the background keeps the stdin/stdout/stderr handles they get from the shell that ran it unless you tell that shell to run redirections replacing them with something else. When `start.sh` reaches out to that daemon over the network, the daemon still has the handle, so it's still able to log, even though `start.sh` and its children have no handle and can't do any logging directly.

Comment: Anyhow -- do the above comments explain things to your satisfaction?

Comment: (another thing you could do to make this a little more visible would be to run `start_linux.sh` in a different terminal window from `start.sh`, and see which window the logs show up in)

Answer (score -1):

It's normally sufficient to just use `subprocess.DEVNULL`, but it's nearly always better to use a `PIPE`

```py
p = subprocess.Pppen(
    command,  # tuple or list, can use shlex.split()
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    # text=True,  # don't need to .encode()
)
out, err = p.communicate()  # opportunity to pass stdin
if p.returncode != 0:
    # handle failure, maybe now display out, err
# now use out for purposes
```

If you process still writes output to the console, it's working around normal output mechanisms and not using the `stdout` and `stderr` streams

Comment: Why would this be better for content you intend to discard? You're paying costs (writes to the FIFO on one side, context-switches, reads on the other side) -- and if setting `DEVNULL` doesn't succeed in suppressing the content, I doubt this will be successful in redirecting it, either.